# how to create a string in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

i want to craete a string which contains `'` character, but whenever i try it fails.

```
SET STR_BUFF = 'SELECT * FROM' || VAR_TABLE || ' WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%';
```

But the procedure doesn't compile. Does DB2 also has some characters like Java where we represent `"` like `\"`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two single quotes to escape the quote character

```
SET STR_BUFF = 'SELECT * FROM' || VAR_TABLE || ' WHERE NAME LIKE ''%abc%'';'
```